# WorldWind High Resolution Textures missing

Tags: java, worldwind

As I zoom in toward Earth, the high resolution textures are missing. I am using the latest version of WorldWind, 2.1.0. Although, the textures are indeed visible on my co-worker's computer and we are running the same code. He had this up and working about a year ago.

At first we thought that he had cached the images and now pulls them offline. I ran our program on the outer net, but no luck. So maybe it has to do with proxies at my work, but I am able to access everything else and I do not receive any network error from any images being loaded.

I'd appreciate any insight to this matter, as I cannot seem to find anyone else with the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worldwind gets images form net and saves them in a local directory (different for each OS, for linux it is `~/var/cache/WorldWindData` and for some windows it is `C:\ProgramData\WorldWindData`). If you are offline, worldwind uses these caches.
You could copy all caches from your co-worker to yourself cache directory.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This did the trick! For anyone w/ Macs, the location is /Library/Caches/WorldWindData. For other OS, see [here](https://forum.worldwindcentral.com/forum/world-wind-java-forums/development-help/12572-where-is-the-cache-folder).